# Выборочное перенаправление ajax-запросов

Tags: javascript, ajax, браузер

`JavaScript`-запрос обращается к некоторому удаленному серверу. Нужно перехватить этот запрос и перенаправить его на `localhost`.

Перехватывать нужно все обращения к этому удаленному ресурсу, но только из конкретной страницы сайта, а не в целом со всех страниц в браузере.

Возможно ли это реализовать хоть какими-либо средствами, учитывая, что правки в сайт вносить нельзя?

Comment: Вы хотите сделать хук на веб сервере? Если да, то сервер какой, кстати?
Или отлавливать это в javascript на странице?

Comment: Приведу пример. Большинство сайтов тянет за собой гугл-аналитику. Я не хочу с одного конкретного сайта отправлять им информацию о моем поведении на сайте. И соответственно все запросы к ним перенаправлять на localhost. Ну или не перенаправлять, а хотя бы просто блокировать. Если рассмотреть вариант добавления в хост-лист  удаленного урла, то тогда закроется обращение на всех сайтах в принципе, а мне нужен один конкретный

Comment: У Вас есть доступ к конфигам веб сервера? И что за сервер ?

Comment: в том то и дело, что к веб-серверу нет доступа, и в принципе вопрос в том, как это на клиентском компьютере настроить, поскольку подразумевается применение этого для любого сайта

Comment: Делайте chrome extension, который будет парсить страницу и вырезать оттуда нежелательный код.